# Accessing the terraform resource configuration within a custom provider

Tags: go, terraform-provider

I am creating a terrorm provider to access data from cloud and on Prem instances, I will be passing the resource type(cloud or onprem) as in the example below

```
    terraform {
  required_providers {
    test = {
      source  = "test-example.com/testprovider/test"
      version = "1.0.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "test" {
    username = var.credentials.username
    password = var.credentials.password
    server = var.credentials.server
}

data "test_onprem" "demoVm" {
name = "appd-tomcat-srv"
}
data "test_cloud" "demoVm" {
name = "appd-tomcat-srv"
}
```

. Now I want to access the resource type is onprem or cloud within the configure function of my provider.

```
func (d *VmDataSource) Configure(ctx context.Context, req datasource.ConfigureRequest, 
resp *datasource.ConfigureResponse) {

}
```